# Dangers of Changing encoding in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an app that collected a sizeable amount of data over the last couple of years, the data is stored in many mysql tables; However all the table were set to

```
Encoding cp1252 West European (latin1)
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
```

There are special chars that do not get displayed properly; I would like to change to

```
Encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I know how to alter the tables but, I do have many tables with ~a million rows of data, what are the dangers in changing all the tables' encodings?

Aside from backing up everything, can I do anything to minimize the risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any character columns as foreign keys, the conversion is safe, as all characters from the first one are present in the second, but with `utf8mb4_general_ci` you might have changes in ordering when sorting rows by character columns. If that's a problem for you, try using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead.

If you have foreign keys, you should disable `foreign_key_checks`, and only enable it back after converting all tables.

Also, the `alter table` will probably lock the table and create a copy, so if you're doing this on a production server, be prepared for some downtime.